# Bridge Wireless Adapter on VM

Tags: networking, virtual-machine

I'm using Mavericks and using Parallel Desktop for Windows 7. I set up wireless network as Bridged Wi-Fi, but Windows 7 looks like still connecting to internet via ethernet. I can't see wireless adapters around me in Windows 7.

[image]

Update: NIC looks like an ethernet device in Device Manager.

Comment: Where is the screenshot that makes you think Windows is using the ethernet device.  Did you pass the connted usb device to the virtual machine?

Comment: I set up wi-fi bridge but can't search wi-fi adapters which are around me.

Comment: That does not answer my question

Comment: I added ss of how I can't see wireless adapters around me.

Comment: You followed the steps outline in this article?  http://pubs.vmware.com/fusion-5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.fusion.help.doc%2FGUID-F081AFAF-7DBB-44FA-BC5B-C41928CFBAE1.html

Comment: But I don't want connect usb to guest os.

Comment: Does device manager see the device.  update your question.  Its not clear the adapter isn't a usb device.

Comment: I would say he's connecting his mac with wifi to his wireless router, but sees a eth connection in the vm, even when in bridged mode. This behaviour is normal (at least in vmware), hence you don't need to manage the wireless connection from the vm. The OS provides the wireless bridge and parallels provides the eth port to the vm. just a guess...

Comment: Gotschi is right about my problem! Is there a way for manage wireless connection from guest os? I don't want use boot camp for my second os.